# Automatically scroll screen in vim when near top/bottom?

Tags: vim, editor

I would like to have smarter screen scrolling when I'm editing. When I reach within X number of lines from the top/bottom of the screen, I would like it to scroll the screen as I continue moving the cursor (so I can always see, at minimum, X lines below or above).

I know `ctrl-y` and `ctrl-e` will scroll, but is there a way I can have vim detect when I hit `j` or `k` how far I am from the top/bottom of the screen so it can move the screen as needed?
 I also know `zz` will center on the current cursor location, but I'd like there to be an area where it doesn't scroll.

Thanks.

Comment: Somehow mine was set to 9, and I found the behavior annoying because when I went to double-click some text to change it as I normally do, my screen jumps and it screws me up. So keep this in mind if you enable this.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

From my .vimrc:

```
set scrolloff=3 " Keep 3 lines below and above the cursor
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the default in global `vimrc` has recently changed from `0` to `5`. Or is it just GitBash. I prefer `set scrolloff=0`.

Answer (score 7):

Try `scrolloff=9999`. After cursor reaches middle of the screen, pressing <kbd>j</kbd> moves the screen up by one, instead of moving the cursor down. Works great once you get used to it.

Answer (score 5):

You might to also look at scrolljump which sets the number of lines scrolled when hitting the "border" set by scrolljump.